# How to update badge count while app is open?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using [BottomNavigationBar](https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar) plugin and it works fine.

My problem is I want to update badge count when notification is received while app is in running mode(i.e. open). I am using [Setting Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) for Xamarin and store count in that. On app initialize it display counts properly. But when my app is open I am changing value of Setting and immediately change the value of badge. How's that can be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Where is several ways to do this.

First, if you are using Xamarin forms then you can use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center). It is cross platform Event Bus implementation.

I used Xamarin.Form. Example for sending message

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var count = 0;
        _button.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, int>(this, "MyMessage", count++);
        };
    }
```

Example of reciever

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var mp = new MainPage();
        MainPage = new MainPage();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, int>(this, "MyMessage", (sender, arg) => {
            MainPage.DisplayAlert("MyMessage", $"Hit Count: {arg}", "ok");
        });

    }
```

There is more info and examples if you check [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

Second, add event to your settings class, and invoke it in your setter

Comment: Please, Can you share any example or code snippet for these?